# Wifi not detected with tripolar adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem, rj-11

I recently moved to a new apartment. There are both a RJ-11 socket and a tripolar socket. If I connect my modem to the RJ-11 socket, there are no problems: I can access Internet both with the LAN wire and the wifi. But if I connect the modem to the tripolar socket (with a tripolar adapter), I can access Internet only with a wire: no device can detect the wireless network. The strange thing is that if I access the modem's control panel while wired, I can see that the wifi is active and there are no problems (even the modem lights are ok as usual). But I cannot detect it!
What is the difference and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: 1. Theres an error in your question, it reads "if I connect to tripolar" both times, one should be RJ11 I suspect.

Comment: 2. That doesnt make sense at all. Try manually setting the wireless channel to CH1 to test in case its causing it to automatically use CH13

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Comment: I tried every channel from 1 to 13. The only one that exhibited some result was 12: the network was detexted but the signal strength oscillates from max to 0 continuosly. My neighbours are using channels 6, 11, 13

Comment: Very very strange. The only way I can conceive of that happening is either the adapter is earthing the line and drawing current out of the modem or its creating a large amount of RFI and destroying your reception. What is the exact other socket, is it Finnish 3 pin?

Comment: Hi, the problem was the jumper inside the socket :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the jumper inside the socket. Now it works fine.